# How do I set the password length in a TextBox?

Tags: c#, .net, textbox

i want to set length of the textbox as 8. when the length is 8 keys become disabled. and also backspace enable.

Comment: Please clarify what framework you're using.  ASP.NET, WinForms, WPF, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

For an HTML text box

```
<input type="password" id="txtPassword" maxlength="8" />
```

For an asp.net textbox

```
<asp:TextBox MaxLength="8" TextMode="Password" runat="server" ID="txtPassword"></asp:TextBox>
```

For a Windows forms textbox

```
txtPassword.MaxLength = 8;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP.NET, then simply set the MaxLength attribute to 8. On any textbox that will limit the number characters. In Windows Forms or WPF, TextBox controls also have a MaxLength property.